# MongoDB min/max aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I've got documents with this simplified schema :

```
{
   positon: 10,
   value: 5,
   count: 3
}
```

What I'd like to compute, is to group those documents by `position` and find the maximum `value` where the count is greater than 4 but with `value` less than the minimum `value` where the count is less than 4.

Here what I've done, but it does not work :

```
{ $group: { 
          _id: {
                   position: "$position",
                 },
          result: {$max: { $cond: [ {$and: [  {$gte: ["$count", 4]}, 
                                              {$lt: ["$value", {$min: { $cond: [ {$lt: ["$count", 4]}, 
                                                                                 { value: "$value" },  
                                                                                 10]
                                                                      }                                                              
                                                               }]
                                             }]},
                                    { value: "$value", nb: "$count"}, 
                                    0] 
                        }
                }
          }
}
```

I am said that `$min`is an invalid operator and I cant figure out how to write the right aggregation function. Would it be better to run a mapreduce ?

If for example I have those documents

```
{Position: 10, value: 1, count 5}
{Position: 10, value: 3, count 3}
{Position: 10, value: 4, count 5}
{Position: 10, value: 7, count 4}
```

I'd like the reslt to be

```
{Position: 10, value: 1, count 4}
```

As it is the maximum of 'value' where count is greater than 4 but also as there is a value of 3 that has only 3 counts so that the value 4 is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bit of a mouthful to say the least but I'll have another crack at explaining it:

You want:

> For each "Position" value find the document whose "value" is less than the the largest "value" of the document with a "count" of less than four, whose own "count" is actually greater than 4.

Which reads like a math exam problem designed to confuse you with the logic. But catching that meaning then you perform the aggregation with the following steps:

```js
db.positions.aggregate([
    // Separate the values greater than and less than 4 by "Position"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$Position",
        "high": { "$push": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": ["$count", 4] },
                { "value": "$value", "count": "$count" },
                null
            ]
        }},
        "low": { "$push": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$lt": ["$count", 4] },
                { "value": "$value", "count": "$count" },
                null
            ]
        }}
    }},

    // Unwind the "low" counts array
    { "$unwind": "$low" },

    // Find the "$max" value from the low counts
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "high": { "$first": "$high" },
        "low":  { "$min": "$low.value" }
    }},

    // Unwind the "high" counts array
    { "$unwind": "$high" },

    // Compare the value to the "low" value to see if it is less than
    { "$project": {
         "high": 1,
         "lower": { "$lt": [ "$high.value", "$low" ] }
    }},

    // Sorting, $max won't work over multiple values. Want the document.
    { "$sort": { "lower": -1, "high.value": -1 } },

    // Group, get the highest order document which was on top
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "value": { "$first": "$high.value" },
        "count": { "$first": "$high.count" }
    }}
])
```

So from the set of documents:

```js
{ "Position" : 10, "value" : 1, "count" : 5 }
{ "Position" : 10, "value" : 3, "count" : 3 }
{ "Position" : 10, "value" : 4, "count" : 5 }
{ "Position" : 10, "value" : 7, "count" : 4 }
```

Only the first is returned in this case as it's value is less than the "count of three" document where it's own count is greater than 4.

```js
{ "_id" : 10, "value" : 1, "count" : 5 }
```

Which I am sure is what you actually meant.

So the application of [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) really only applies when getting discrete values from documents out of a grouping range. If you are interested in more than one value from the document or indeed the whole document, then you are **sorting** and getting the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) entries on the grouping boundary.

And aggregate is much faster than mapReduce as it uses native code without invoking a JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: Wah! I was thinking of making two arrays of greater than / lower than count 4 but after....? I'll try to understand your proposal and see if it works. And no, that's not a math exam lol and i dont mind of the performances as my database is not so big and surely not queried real time. Thanks!!

Comment: @G_A More of a comment to how complex the problem was presented, but I generally understand your angle on what you were trying to achieve. At least I think I do. So therefore I tried to explain a reasonable approach.

Comment: I've tried your approach and I think I understand each step (I've used your code step by step...). It is not as straight forward as I was thinking. I must really turn my mind from "traditional" programming to database aggregation thinking, it is not natural for me at first (I begin...). Thanks again, I learned a lot !

Comment: @GuillaumeA You're welcome. Thanks for the endorsement. MongoDB does kind of turn the SQL approach on it's head, but that is exactly why it exists. You asked a good and well researched question. Don't feel shy to ask another like it. Well done.

Comment: @GuillaumeA Sorry but the code an general algorithm suits the data you have presented, and basically even if you expand upon the same lines. Perhaps if your use case does not suit these means then you should post that as another question. It is generally a good idea to actually post your questions with real rather than abstract data, otherwise you will come across these problems in understanding the implementation.

Comment: The sample data I posted represents well the data I really have. The behaviour is the same. What I did not realize was that the `$first` command return indeed the first non null element of an array. I was not looking at all my data to confirm that your algo works. I also tried to sort the high array before getting the first item, and the behaviour is the same (sorting = unwinding + projection + sorting + grouping).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51193/discussion-between-neil-lunn-and-guillaumea)